# How to save the result of an ImageMagick operation as a new file

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I realize this is probably **very** basic, but I have looked around for answers to no avail.

How do I save the result of an ImageMagick operation from the command line, and not modify the original file (this would be the equivalent of `save as` in a program with a GUI.  For instance, how can I save `resize 10 10 a.jpg` to a new file? just appending a new file name to the end of that command results in `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`convert infile.jpg -options outfile.jpg`

or your example :

`convert a.jpg -resize 10x10 out.jpg`

Comment: But what about for different operations, such as drawing on the existing image and then saving it as a new file? `mogrify old.jpg -draw "text 24, 50" new.jpg` doesn't work

Comment: From the Mogrify documentation : "This tool is similiar to convert except that the original image file is overwritten (unless you change the file suffix with the -format option)"